# Add page to pdf in php

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I need to add into pdf file one page after already existing first page and into this added page write text. I read somewhere, that Zend framework can do it, but I have no idea how.

Thanks in advance for answer

Comment: I am not sure but last time I have checked the Zend Framework add 900 pages of documentations and probably 10 or more around Zend_Pdf..

Comment: Have you at least tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a pdf object and assign it to a variable:

```
$pdf = pdf_new();
```

Then you need to read your pdf file into the object:

```
pdf_open_file($pdf, "path/to/your/pdf/file.pdf");
```

Now, you add a (A4) page to the pdf object:

```
pdf_begin_page($pdf, 595, 842);
```

Then, before you can write text to the page, you need to grab a font:

```
$arial = pdf_findfont($pdf, "Arial", "host", 1);
```

And state that you will be using this font:

```
pdf_setfont($pdf, $arial, 10);
```

Now you can write text to the page with:

```
pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Text to write to the page.", 50, 750);
```

We're done with the page, so close it with:

```
pdf_end_page($pdf);
```

Finally, close and save the file:

```
pdf_close($pdf);
```

Credit: [Generate PDFs with PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-pdfs-php/)
Other good tutorials:

- [How To: Create PDF With Php](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Create-Pdf-Php_t4972.html)
- [PDF Generation Using Only PHP -
  Part 2](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1255)

Comment: As I understand Majid Fouladpour's answer, it purely *appends*--it writes only to the end of the existing PDF content.  Is that what original questioner Lukáš Jelič intended, or does the latter want to *insert* a page?  While I *think* he wants exactly the append answer provided, I'm unsure.  Both are feasible, of course.